Server Send Events, EventSource on the web, for each event all previous data are send again?
Using PostgreSQL, PHP, JavaScript
Background
When I'm on the webpage and something updates on the database I want to receive a notification so I can query some data and update the page accordingly or receive the result of a query immediately to avoid in one step, went with the second one.
At first I tried setting this up myself, I did make an AJAX request to a PHP script that was using LISTEN on the database and when a related NOTIFY occured else where, it listened to it, queried the data and AJAX received it.
I noticed that each time I received all the previous data and the latest ones in the response after a NOTIFY.
So it was hard to parse and get only the latest response + the bandwidth used with each response was getting bigger and bigger. The webpage may have to run for 4-5 hours without refreshing may less, in either I researched a bit more and found out EventSource. It does my job and it gives only the last response each time.
Question
So my question is, am I fine with the following PHP and JavaScript or EventSource has the same issue I had but it hides it? Do I have to do something like restarting the EventSource every now and then to avoid too much data being send with each new response? Is there something I am missing?
const event_source = new EventSource("/_update.php?for=secretary");

event_source.addEventListener("update", (e) => {
    update(JSON.parse(e.data));
});

event_source.addEventListener("uerror", (e) => {
    alert("Updating from EventSource does not work properly: " + e.data);
    event_source.close();
});

<?php

// script: _update.php

enum Event : string {
    case UPDATE = 'update';
    case ERROR  = 'uerror';
}

enum Parameter : string {
    case FOR = 'for';
}

// ---

ob_implicit_flush(false);

function produce(Event $event, string $data) : void {
    echo "event:{$event->value}\ndata:{$data}\n\n";
    flush();
}

// ---

if (isset($_GET) === false || isset($_GET[Parameter::FOR->value]) === false) {
    produce(Event::ERROR, "use GET method and parameter '".Parameter::FOR->value."'\n");
    exit(0);
}

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/.private/database.php';

$db = database();

$request_data = [
    'secretary' => function () use ($db) : array  {
        return $db->retrieve("interviewee");
    }
];

$for = $_GET[Parameter::FOR->value];

if (in_array($for, array_keys($request_data)) === false) {
    produce(Event::ERROR, "unknown value of '" . Parameter::FOR->value . "' parameter: {$for}\n");
    exit(0);
}

// ---

header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("X-Accel-Buffering: no");

try {
    $conf = (require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/.private/config.php')['dbms'];

    $listener = new PDO(
        "pgsql:host={$conf['host']};dbname={$conf['dbname']}", $conf['user'], $conf['password'],
        [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ]
    );
    
    $listener->exec("LISTEN " . Postgres::$UPDATE_CHANNEL . ";");
    
    while (connection_aborted() === 0) {

        $notification = $listener->pgsqlGetNotify(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 25_000); // at 30_000 php timesout

        if ($notification === false) {
            continue;
        }

        produce(Event::UPDATE, json_encode($request_data[$for]()));
    }

    $listener = null;
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    produce(Event::ERROR, $e->getMessage());
}


